# Show/hide image depending on variable

Tags: javascript, css, image, variables, visibility

Please don't judge me. I'm pretty new to HTML/jS/css.

Been trying to figure out how to add a show/hide function for an image that functions as a button based on Variable. But seems like there's no one out there with any proper answer to my issue.

```
<img src="myIMG" id="HideShowButt" onclick="gainResource2()"></img>

var resource1 = 0;
```

Basically, what I wanted to do is something like this;

```
function HideShowButt() {
    if(resource1 >= 0.1){
          document.getElementById("HideShowButt").style.visibility= "visible";
    }   
    else{ document.getElementById("HideShowButt").style.visibility= "hidden";
    }
}
```

The image is a clickable object with transparrent background which lays on top of another image. The point is, I don't want to show this image until the user has gained a certain value on Resource1.

Is there any solution to this, am I missing something obvious or this the absolute wrong way of doing it? 
Keep in mind, I'm trying to keep this in simple jS/html/css.
Thanks in advance !

Comment: For a start you haven't closed your image tag and you are calling a different function `gainResource2()`. If this is a copy/paste mistake please update your source code within the question to make things more clear to work with. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Styling in CSS is done with the display tag:

```
document.getElementById("HideShowButt").style.display = "none";
```

resp.

```
document.getElementById("HideShowButt").style.display = "block"
```

Comment: Using `.style.visibility` is also fine. The only difference is it will hide the image leaving a blank space where the image should be. So by changing the `style` as you have suggested isn't going to fix the existing problem.

Comment: The image is an object with transparent background which lays on top of another image. So by getting the function work as I want, it'll hide an object in an image(sort of).